# SED using variables that includes new lines

Tags: sed

I have these two vars (the empty space is to be included and have new line):

oldValue:

```
    related_pg_pin : vph;
    value : 8;
```

newValue:

```
    related_pg_pin : vph;
    value : 11500;
```

And I want to substitute the oldValue with newValue. I'm using this command:

```
sed -i "s/${oldValue}/${newValue}/g" $file
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
 /bin/sed: -e expression #1, char 27: unterminated `s' command
```

Any idea what is the source of the problem? I've tried several things but none works.

Comment: Prefix your command with `echo ` (with space) and show its output.

Comment: sed -i s/    related_pg_pin : vph;
    value : 8;/    related_pg_pin : vph;
    value : 11500;/g file_path

Comment: This works fine for me: `sed "s/ related_pg_pin : vph; value : 8;/ related_pg_pin : vph; value : 11500;/g" file_path`

Comment: I think the problem was related to new line character. I'm still struggling to get it working properly but at least it doesn't return an error

Comment: @miguelfcp Please revisit your old questions and consider accepting an answer if the solution worked for you. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

This `sed` may work for you.

```
$ sed -zi "s/\n//;s/$(sed -z 's/\n//' <<< $oldValue)/$(sed -z 's/\n//' <<< $newValue)/;s/;/&\n/" input_file
    related_pg_pin : vph;
    value : 11500;
```

Comment: I'm using tcl shell it didn't work. But thanks for trying to help me :)

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative solution in my script. In the end I used a simple sed command. Thank you everyone!

Comment: Please include how you solved this, perhaps sharing your code (if possible), in case someone has this problem in the future.